# mysql cyrillic and latin records

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

So, I have a situation where records in MySql Db are both in cyrillic nad latin alphabet.

I would like to return both latin and cyrilic result, no matter in which alphabeth I do my query.

For example: if I enter 'dog' I would like to return both 'dog' and 'дог'.

Is this even possible? What are the best practice to handle this kind of DB records?

Comment: It'd be handy if you at least told us what you're programming in.

Comment: Are you asking about the _transliteration_ from 'dog' to Cyrillic 'дог'?  Or the _translation_ from 'dog' to the Russian equivalent?  (Perhaps that is 'собака'?)

Comment: For _storing_ latin _and_ cyrillic, use `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case much like a soundex. A soundex is the string value converted to a phonetic format.

Basically, you write a function that converts any input to a generally queryable language-independent phonetic format, with specific rules of what certain characters or groups of characters convert to.

In your database, you add a soundex column to your table, and make sure that any entry saved in the database has its soundex filled in with the the result of your inserted value processed by that soundex function.

Once you have that, any input you get can be processed through the soundex function too, and then looked up in the soundex column of the table.